# Inserting entered value into sql query using python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I can't quite seem to figure this one out. I've just started playing with Python today so I'm not exactly a pro.

I want to get the user to input a value and then that value to be inserted into my SQL query. What I've managed to do so far from googling is below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import pyodbc

try:
    con = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=server;DATABASE=MSTAR;UID=ADMIN;PWD=***;Trusted_Connection=yes')
    cursor = con.cursor()

except Exception as e:
    sys.exit('Cant connect')

Machine=input('Enter MachineID: ')


cursor.execute("""SELECT TOP 1 [STATE_ID] FROM [STAR].[dbo].[P_GPS] where MACHINE_ID like %s""", (Machine))
result = cursor.fetchall()

print result
```

Comment: With this being the error:

PS C:\Users\adam.hand\Desktop> python test.py
Enter Machine: 150
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    cursor.execute("""SELECT TOP 1 [STATE_ID] FROM [STAR].[dbo].[P_GPS] where MACHINE_ID like %s""",
))
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Comment: Use `?` instead of `%s`.